# How to stop and delete all processing background jobs in hangfire?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, backgroundworker, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire in AspNet Core project to run some background jobs. When I restart my server, new backround job enqueued and processing, but all previous background jobs continuous processing or restarting. I have removed all old processing background jobs from database, but nothing changed, this deleted job was removed from database but still processing. How can I stop and delete all processing background jobs, which are not reflect in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use [cancellation tokens](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html). In you job, pass an IJobCancellationToken object as argument along your other arguments:

```
public void MyJob( <<other args>>, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

To enqueue your job pass IJobCancellationToken as null:

```
string jobID = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyJob(<<other args>>, JobCancellationToken.Null));
```

Now to cancel and remove a job, do it through code:

```
BackgroundJob.Delete(jobID);
```

Comment: Why is cancel token necessary ? Is this because job might have already triggered its method at the time delete is called ?  But for many operations we must check cancel token and throw exception at very top of method. Only a few operations ( such as loops ) would have other junctures where it would make sense to potentially stop processing by check cancel token and throw exception.  So one would think that for many use-cases the only realistic strategy is cancellation must prevent the job from calling its method.

Comment: Have you tried this for local debug session ?  Because it would be nice to either cancel all jobs before session ends or on first opportunity at startup. I'm not sure it's possible during session shutdown.  Startup would need to load all jobs from data store and delete/cancel before any jobs queued-up -- but is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete the Hangfire jobs from the Hangfire dashboard.